# Query ServiceFeatureTable with CreationDate in whereClause in ArcGIS java

Tags: java, where-clause, arcgis, query-string, arcgis-runtime

I am trying to query the `ServiceFeatureTable` using ArcGIS java. If we use REST service to query we can query based on the **CreationDate**. I am trying to do the same thing using ArcGIS java. runtime SDK as below

```
 ServiceFeatureTable featureTable = new ServiceFeatureTable(url);
 QueryParameters query = new QueryParameters();
 query.setWhereClause("CreationDate >= '1527671854180'");
 query.setReturnGeometry(true);
 ListenableFuture<FeatureQueryResult> queryFeaturesAsync = featureTable.queryFeaturesAsync(query);
```

But it is giving `com.esri.arcgisruntime.io.JsonEmbeddedException: Cannot perform query. Invalid query parameters.`

Is it possible to query `ServiceFeatureTable` based on the **CreationDate**?*emphasized text*

Comment: What is the field type for `CreationDate` in the feature service? You'll find it in the REST endpoint. It should be something like `esriFieldTypeInteger` or `esriFieldTypeDate`.

Comment: type is `esriFieldTypeDate` and sqlType is `sqlTypeOther`

Comment: Have you tried without the single quotes? "CreationDate >= 1527671854180"?